# Old user data persistent after new user signing in on the same phone | Multiprovider

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

The scenario I'm facing is that when user A signs in his data shows perfectly throughout the app, but when he signs out and user B signs in, user A's data gets shown instead of user B's.

main.dart

```dart
runApp(
   MultiProvider(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      providers: [
         Provider<AuthService>(
           create: (_) => AuthService(),
         ),
         ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserModel()),
         Provider<DatabaseService>(
            create: (_) => DatabaseService(),
         ),
      ],
      child: const MyApp()
   )
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home:StreamBuilder(
       stream: Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false).user,
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print("Error");
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Home();
            } else {
              return SignUp();
            }
          },
       ),
     );
  }
}
```

AuthService.dart

```dart
class AuthService {
  Stream? get user => _auth.userChanges();
    
  Future<void> signIn(
      String email, String password) async {
              UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  }
  Future<void> signOut() async {
     await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

So far I've tried:

1. Deleting cache directory and app directory when user signs out (didn't work)
2. Adding unique key to the `MultiProvider` (didn't work)

When I restart the app everything works perfectly and the correct user's data shows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a simple but idiotic work around .

I used restart_app package and on logout just called Restart.restartapp();

Made it blend in and works for now .

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've looked at this package and it would indeed fix the issue, but I'll turn to it if I don't find any useful answers. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.